# Application Insights logging provider not working in AspNetCore 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, azure-application-insights

An Application Insights event is not created when calling `logger.LogError("My error.")` from my web API. I'm confirming this in two ways:

- F5 debugging in Visual Studio 2017 (v15.5.7) does not show any Application Insights events in the Output/Events pane.
- No events flow to my Application Insights instance in Azure.

I suspect my problem is due the application's logging factory not being configured correctly with `ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider`. It was my understanding from reading articles and source code, I should:

1. `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry` on my services collection to ensure TelemetryClient is registered. See [ApplicationInsightsExtensions](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/blob/3dcab5b92ebddc92e9010fc707cc7062d03f92e4/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/Extensions/ApplicationInsightsExtensions.cs)
2. `AddApplicationInsights` on my `ILoggerFactory` to register the provider and use the client mentioned above. See [ApplicationInsightsLoggerFactoryExtensions](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/blob/edbdca20b3c87358825e17096251fcb64de5d47b/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/Logging/Implementation/ApplicationInsightsLoggerFactoryExtensions.cs)

I'm doing something wrong I'm sure, but I cannot determine what it is. I've boiled my code down to the skeleton below, and I am able to repro my issue still.

I came across a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45022693/3897362) on StackOverflow, however, the answer did not solve my case.

**WebApplication.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            BuildWebHost( args ).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost( string[] args ) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder( args )
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
    "ApplicationInsights": {
        "InstrumentationKey": "omitted for StackOverflow"
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup( IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory )
    {
        this.LoggerFactory = loggerFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( loggerFactory ) );

        this.Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath( hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath )
            .AddJsonFile( "appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true )
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
    }

    IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory { get; }

    public void Configure( IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env )
    {
        app.UseMvc();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry( this.Configuration );
        this.LoggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights( services.BuildServiceProvider(), LogLevel.Information );

        services.AddMvc();
    }
}
```

**MyController.cs**

```
[Route( "[controller]" )]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public MyController( ILogger<MyController> logger )
    {
        this.Logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( logger ) );
    }

    ILogger<MyController> Logger { get; }

    [HttpGet]
    public void Get()
    {
        // *************************************************************************
        // This line is not being captured as an Application Insights Event.
        // *************************************************************************
        this.Logger.LogError( "My error." );
        // *************************************************************************
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I learned `ILoggerFactory loggerFactory` can be dependency injected into `Startup.Configure()`. After calling `AddApplicationInsights` on this instance of the logger factory instead of the one saved from my `Startup` constructor, everything worked as expected.

Only `Startup` class needed to be modified from my original question. Here's it is for completeness of this answer.

```
public Startup( IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment )
{
    this.Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath( hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath )
        .AddJsonFile( "appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true )
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
}

IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

public void Configure( IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory )
{
    loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights( app.ApplicationServices, LogLevel.Information );
    app.UseMvc();
}

public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry( this.Configuration );
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

**Learning opportunity!**

If someone more familiar with Application Insights and AspNetCore 2.0 can explain to me why this works compared to the original question's code, I'd be very curious to know! :)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way (as you found out already) to configure AI logging is to call extension method AddApplicationInsights() in Configure method. When you called this method from ConfigureServices() instead, I believe AILoggingProvider got a TelemetryClient which was not configured yet.
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/blob/develop/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/Logging/Implementation/ApplicationInsightsLoggerFactoryExtensions.cs#L65