# How do I find application insights logs for specific ILogger<T>

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I use asp.net core logging like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyClass> _logger;
    public readonly EventId NoEntryFoundEventId = new EventId(1, "No Entry Found");

    public MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Foo(decimal entryId)
    {
        _logger.LogError(NoEntryFoundEventId, "MyCustomMessage\t: Entry ID: {EntryId}", entryId);         
    }
}
```

An I setup the logger like this:

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices, LogLevel.Information)
```

How do I find the logs for MyClass in Azure portal?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking: What type is ILogger?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've included to logger registration in the question: `loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices, LogLevel.Information)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to find the log entries in Application Insights that are specifically linked to your class `MyClass`.

It is in the Property "CategoryName".

[Getting Started with Application Insights for ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Application-Insights-for-ASP.NET-Core)

Your program.cs should look something like this

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
  WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseApplicationInsights()
    .Build();
```

Then [link the ASP.NET ILogger to Application Insights](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Logging)

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
/*...existing code..*/
        loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices, LogLevel.Warning);
}
```

If you set it up like this, your ILogger will automatically use the full name of MyClass as a category name, and you will see that in Application Insights under the property "CategoryName".

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/tree/develop/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/Logging/Implementation

```
private void PopulateTelemetry(ITelemetry telemetry, 
   IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>> stateDictionary, EventId eventId)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> dict = telemetry.Context.Properties;
        dict["CategoryName"] = this.categoryName;
...
```

See also this question for an image on how this will look in Application Insights:
[Using Application Insights with ILoggerFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022693/using-application-insights-with-iloggerfactory)
[image]
(Image is taken directly from this answer, please tell me if this is not allowed and I will remove it)

The data is added as a "custom property" and can be filtered like that in the portal:
[image]

Some more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics#properties
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-tour#custom-properties-and-measurements

Comment: Hi, this explains how the log looks like, but could you elaborate on how to find it (filter by CategoryName) in Azure Portal?